# Model IList returning null value

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my model class:

```
public class BillOfLading{
// Tracking Number
    public string tracking_number { get; set; }
    public string current_status { get; set; }
    public int bol_user_id { get; set; }
    public IList<HazmatDesc> HazmatDesc { get; set; } 
}
public class HazmatDesc
{
    public int Id { set; get; }

    [Display(Name = "NMFC Item NO.")]
    public int? nmfc_item_no { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "NMFC Sub")]
    public int? nmfc_sub { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Pieces")]
    public int pieces { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Package Type")]
    public string package_type { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "HM")]
    public bool hm { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string description_articles { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Class")]
    public string hazmat_class { set; get; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Weight(lbs.)")]
    public int hazmat_weight { set; get; }
}
```

}

When I save the data through model it works fine and all values in HazmatDesc get stored in database which also saves the ID of BillOfLading Model.

The problem is when I am trying to retrieve BillOfLading there are no values in HazmatDesc:

[image]

This the the record in database with BillOfLading_ID:

[image]

I have tried to retrieve the Hazmatdesc by using BillOfLading_ID but it doesn't work.

Even when a create a scaffold edit template for model BillOfLading HazmatDesc data is not there.

Is there anyway to overcome this or maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Do you call the find method, with ID = 1? Can you remove 'ID' and insert '1' for test?

Comment: The id comes from the view: @Html.ActionLink("Print BOL", "PrintBol", new { id=item.ID })

Comment: If you see in the screenshot there is data coming in the model for example the purchase_order_number.

Comment: Have you checked the configuration of the context? Lazyloading,...

Comment: Does `db.BillOfLading.Include("HazmatDesc").Single(b => b.Id == id)` work?

Comment: Great. thefiloe was on the right track. It is lazy loading. I'd recommend you read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx